# Escape charaters are staying in my std::string

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, std

I am setting up a string like so:

```
 std::string findOldString("<option value=\"" + std::to_string(--selectedVideoNumber) + "\">");
```

Which requires the quotes around the selectedVideoNumber so I have used the esacape charated "\". The problem is when findOldString is created it still has those escape backslashes in and is therefore failing the next step.

The expected string is:

```
<option value="1">
```

not:

```
<option value=\"1\">
```

which is the one being created above

Is this expected behaviour? How do I remove them?

Comment: How did you check what the created value is?

Comment: using the IDE and looking at the variable

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/XrMOp7)

Answer (score 1):

The VS debugger adds the slashes to aid readability. They are not present in the original string. If you print it, you'll see that they are not included.